# Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object in yii2

Tags: file-upload, yii2, fatal-error

I am trying to run an application in Yii2
I tried to upload a user profile picture and it works greatly
but the problem starts when I try to update the name file. It shows me an error like `Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object`.
I even tried to update without any changes.. even that time also show me the same error...
but error goes if I change the pic.
this is my controller

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        // get the instance of uploaded file
        $imageName = $model->user_username;
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'user_avatar');

        $model->file->saveAs( '/uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension );

        //save the path in DB..
        $model->user_avatar = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
        $model->save();

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->user_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The model rules

```
  public function rules()
            {
                return [

                [['user_email', 'user_password'], 'required'],
                    // [['user_password'], 'required'],
                    [['user_username'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
                    [['user_first_name'], 'required'],
                    [['user_app_user_id'], 'required',
                    [['user_type','user_app_name','user_status'], 'string'],
                    [['user_app_user_id'], 'integer'],
                    [['user_rememberMe'], 'boolean'],
                    [['user_first_name', 'user_last_name'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
                    [['user_email'], 'string', 'max' => 150],
                    [['user_password'], 'string', 'min'=>6],
                    [['user_password'], 'string', 'max' => 40,
                    [['user_avatar'],'file'],
                    //[['user_avatar'], 'string', 'max' => 500],
                    [['user_verification_code','user_auth_key'], 'string'],
                    [['user_email'], 'email'],
                    [['user_email'], 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],

                    ];
            }
```

Comment: if you `var_dump($model->file);`  what's in there? probably not a file object.

Comment: but i already uploaded a file and saved in my db...

Comment: then you'll have to find out why `UploadedFile::getInstance()` doesn't return a valid object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code requires file upload. You should just add condition here:

```
if ($model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'user_avatar')) {
    $model->file->saveAs( '/uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension );
    //save the path in DB..
    $model->user_avatar = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
    $model->save();
}
```

Comment: The problem still there....
I think the problem can be resolved if we should first check whether the value of user_avatar is in DB..
if the value is there do not consider the user_avatar else consider the user_avatar...and update the user...
Currently i am working on that code....Unfortunately not working....
Thank you for your answer....

Comment: Than I need to see error message details. It would be better if you had debug mode on.

Comment: Thank you Pavel...
Error gone.. but when i uploaded the user the user_avatar field in became empty...I cant choose avatar each time...I  want the image saved in DB to display if I didnt change the avatar  in to new

Comment: Could you add your model rules() method body to the problem description?

Comment: Uploading and saving on creating profile works fine. But on update, user_avatar goes empty if I am not uploading it again!

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't have an idea why does it update user_avatar. But I can suggest you a workaround - you may remove user_avatar from rules at all and use 'file' attribute instead as it's for file anyway. This leads to change form file field attribute and "$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');" too. It also looks a little bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'user_avatar');
$ext = substr(strrchr($model->file,'.'),1);
if($ext != null)
{                
   $newfname = $model->user_username.'.'.$ext;
   $model->file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') .'/uploads/' .$model->user_avatar = $newfname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is right answear but simetimes We just have to unset img model required rules:

namespace app\models;

```
[['img','post_img'], 'required'],  -<<<<Delete this
```

Just after deleting requirde rule my troubles gone. Hope that can help for somebody.